# Prove that relation is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have relation:

$a, b$ from $N(a,b)\in R$ only if $a+b$ is odd.

How can I prove that relation is an equivalence relation?
Please explain to me.

Comment: What is $N(a, b)$? And I don't see how this can be an equivalence relation since it is not reflexive: $a + a = 2a$ is even so $(a, a)$ is not in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an equivalence relation.

Note that this relation is not transitive.

For example, $(1,2) \in R$ and $(2,3) \in R$, but $(1,3) \notin R$.

Comment: Why 1,3 is not transitive?

Comment: Because $(1,3) \in R$ only if $1+3=4$ is odd, which is false.

Comment: Is that means that 1,3 is correct transitive relation, but sum of 1 and 3 is even?